# XNA game tutorial

Tags: .net, xna, xnanimation

I have been coding for a while in C# and want to learn XNA game development, I have googled around but unable to find a good tutorial. Can someone provide link to some tutorial that can teach me from the begining.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft offers a lot for this, you could start with:

- [Getting Started with XNA Game Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894.aspx)
- [XNA Creators club 2d tutorial for beginners](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/gettingstarted/bg2d/chapter1)

And don't forget the complete XNA Creator's Club online:

- [XNA Creators Club](http://creators.xna.com/en-US)

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend Riemers tutorials, along with others already recommended.

http://www.riemers.net/

Comment: riemer makes some cool stuff really easy to learn... riemers was my first tutorial in 3d game programming... now a friend and i have a game on steam

Answer (score 5):

There's an introduction tutorial on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/xna1.aspx) here about XNA games, there is also a step-by-step version of [Space Invaders](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/xnaspaceinvaders.aspx) using XNA also on CodeProject. Here is also a car simulator on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/Simcars.aspx) also. Do a search there using the keyword 'XNA' and you will be very surprised! :)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 4):

- http://creators.xna.com/
- http://nickgravelyn.com/archive/
- http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/blogindex.html
- http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/samples-tutorials-tools/
- http://www.catalinzima.com/?page_id=10

Answer (score 2):

i'll recommend 3D buzz tutorials for newbies

see my post :

video tutorial links are at the bottom :

http://hackmyass.wordpress.com/tag/xna-framework/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.riemers.net/ is great, I used this a lot when learning XNA. Also, I wrote a little tutorial in making a clone of Pong in XNA 4.0 you can take a look at if you like. http://ross-warren.co.uk/pong-clone-in-xna-4-0-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Visit the XNA Creators Club website: http://creators.xna.com/. There are loads of good tutorials. Googling around should have helped!!

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation to Riemers tutorials. I would also like to add a helpful debugging library to the list. XNA Debug Terminal is an open source library you can setup in seconds that allows you to see the value of any variable, invoke any method, watch values changing in real-time, and more by simply typing c# code into a terminal-like display that appears atop your game window. Unlike the normal Visual Studio debugger, you can invoke arbitrary code while your game is running. You can find out more about this at http://www.protohacks.net/xna_debug_terminal . This will greatly help you to avoid a lot of frustration while learning XNA.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend James Silva's book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Building-XNA-2-0-Games-Professionals/dp/1430209798](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209798)

He's an author of two XBLA titles and many successful XBLIG titles.